# Spark SQL how to use Filter

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have written the following SQL :

```sql
select  count(value) as total, name , window  from `event` 
   where count(value) > 1 group by window(event_time,'2 minutes'),name
```

Spark is giving me the following error :

```
nAggregate/Window/Generate expressions are not valid in where clause of the query.\nExpression in where clause: [(count(event.`value`) > CAST(1 AS BIGINT))]\nInvalid expressions: [count(event.`value`)]
```

What's the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `HAVING` instead ([documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-having.html)), and it should be put after `GROUP BY`:

```sql
select  count(value) as total, name , window  from `event` 
group by window(event_time,'2 minutes'),name
having total > 1
```